# Ionic text not align

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm used my university project for `Ionic-3`. I have small issue text is not align to first line ,any one know how to align this correctly ?
look my code and live sample [working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eu4uq1)

this is my code

**html**

```
<ion-card-title><ion-icon name="color-palette" item-start class="card-itm-icon"></ion-icon>
 <p class="card-head-txt-skill" text-wrap >
       A paragraph (from the Ancient Greek παράγραφος paragraphos, "to write beside" or "written beside") is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea.     
          </p>

   </ion-card-title>
```

**css**

```
  p.card-head-txt-skill {font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4rem;     text-indent: 4rem;
    margin-top: -3.5rem;text-align: justify;
    text-align-last:left;}

      .card-itm-icon {color: #ff9300; text-indent: 0.5rem; top: -0.8rem;
    position: relative;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I FIXED MY ISSUE

I removed `text-indent: 4rem;` and after  added  this css

```
p.card-head-txt-skill {font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.4rem;    margin-left: 4rem;
    margin-top: -3.5rem;
    }
```